# Is it a sin to not give money (sadaqah) everytime we are asked in the streets?

Tags: money, sadaqah

Salam,

Are we supposed to give money to every person asking in the streets ?

I decided to give a certain amount every Month, but this amount is not enough Big to give everyday to people.. but I Can give more.. it's a weird question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Hadith or Ayat indicating this would be a sin.

However, if you are able to give more amount of money to the people asking then there are more good deeds for you. But even if you have the money (but still got many days left to get your salary) and you decide not to give more money as you said that you already do it then there is no sin in that and no such verse is there to prove that is a sin.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not a sin.

Allah doesn't burden a soul more than it can bear.

> Narrated `Aisha:
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "Do good deeds properly, sincerely and
> moderately and know that your deeds will not make you enter Paradise,
> and that **the most beloved deed to Allah is the most regular and
> constant even if it were little.**"
> [Sahih Bukhari 6464](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6464)

Just do your due diligence and give sadaqah as per your capacity to those who are in real need or poor. As Asan mentioned in his answer, your parents, your relatives, the orphans and those classified as "miskeen" should be given preference.

Try to avoid those who made begging for money a business.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a weird question. It is a good question.

First of all the quran does mention those that have a known right for the needy i.e. it is referring to the people who set aside a known amount for the needy and gives such people glad tidings (70:24-5).

Your ansewer is in surah Baqara, it goes:

They ask thee what they should spend (in charity). Say: Whatever ye spend that is good is for parents and kindred and orphans and those in want and for wayfarers. And whatever ye do that is good―Allah knoweth it well. (215)

......

......

......

.....................................................They ask thee how much they are to spend; say: "What is beyond your needs." Thus doth Allah make clear to you His Signs: in order that ye may consider.― (219)